# RSpec, webrat and escaped characters

Tags: webrat, rspec2, html-escape-characters

I'm using **RSpec 2** with **webrat** in Rails 3 to test my views. I want to make sure the views don't show special characters (like `&ldquo;`). Here is my spec:

```
it 'does not show special HTML characters' do
 get '/'
 response.should_not contain('&ldquo;')
end
```

Problem is webrat parses the `&ldquo;` quotes while the browser - tested in Chrome and Firefox - does not. Is there any way I can tell RSpec or webrat to parse the string a browser would do it?

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: @iWasRobbed No sorry, I didn't find a solution and removed the spec. :(

Answer (score 0):

The way I would solve this problem is to use a text editor that can input these characters directly. So the spec will be defined thus:

```
it 'does not show special HTML characters' do
    get '/'
    response.should_not contain('“')
end
```

Checkout the [ldquo site](http://www.ldquo.net/) for some more information and references to other special characters.